# Google sheets wont filter a query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to filter a Google sheet with columns A to O using a query on a second sheet.  I can put this formula in a new sheet and it pulls all the data just like its supposed to.

```
=query('Inventory'!$A$1:$O, "select * ", 1 )
```

What I am trying to do is filter the spreadsheet with a where clause that is to use a cell dropdown list (generated by unique values in the original sheet).  I have used this formula:

```
=query('Inventory'!$A$1:$O, "select * where B = "&C1&"", 1 )
```

where C1 has the drop down box.  This always gives me the error:

"Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: value" (the value depends on what is selected in the drop down).

It also doesn't work if I wrap the `B = "&C1&"` in parenthesis () which i have seen other posts use.

When I looked at Google's site for their example (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), this should be a no-brainier unless something changed and their site isn't up to date.

I apologize for something this simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=query('Inventory'!$A$1:$O, "select * where B = '"&C1&"'", 1 )
```

Comment: I'-'I has posted the correct answer but just to expand on it a bit, with the syntax that you used it interprets whatever is selected in the drop-down as a column name. So if you were to put B in your drop-down you would select rows where B=B so should see all of your data.

Comment: Thats was definitely it.  I had to add the single quotes on either side of it.  Thanks!

Comment: I still stick to my guns. "&C1&" gives the contents of C1 (interpreted here as a column name). ' "&C1&" ' also gives the contents of C1 but interpreted as a literal.